# How to SORT a SET and GET the full HASH

Tags: redis, phpredis

I'm new to Redis and I have to say I love it till now :)

I'm bumping into an issue I'm not sure how to solve it in the more efficient way.
I have a `SET` of `HASH`. Each `HASH` describe a post.

Here is the code to create and store the `HASH`:

```
// Create the HASH
$key = 'post:'.$post->getId();
$this->redis->hSet($key, 'created', $post->getCreated());
$this->redis->hSet($key, 'author', $post->getAuthor());
$this->redis->hSet($key, 'message', $post->getMessage());

// Store the HASH in the SET
$this->redis->sAdd('posts', $post->getId());
```

Now, previously I was storing all the post's attributes in a `data` field of the `HASH` (json_encoded) and I was fetching the information like this:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array($offset, $limit),
    'get' => 'post:*->data '
));

if (!is_array($data)) {
    return array();
}

foreach ($data as &$post) {
    $post = json_decode($post, true);
}
```

It was working great, I had all the posts information :)

But I had conflicts when updating the post in Redis (concurrent updates), so I've decided to have all the post's attributes in separated `fields` of the `HASH` and it fixed my issue of conflicts.

Now the problem I have is to fetch the `HASH` from my `SET`. Do I have to specify every single fields like this:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array($offset, $limit),
    'get' => array('post:*->created', 'post:*->author', 'post:*->message')
));
```

Or is there another way to fetch the full `HASH` directly within the `SET`?

I heard about `pipeline` but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for and if I can use it with `phpredis`

Cheers, Maxime

---

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure I explained myself clearly. I have some elements in a set (`post_id`).
I want to get the first 10 posts of the `SET`, which means I want 10 `hash` (with all their fields and value) in order to build a `post` object.

I was previously storing all the object information in one field of the hash (`data`), now I have one field per attribute of the object.

before:

`myHash:<id> data`

now:

`myHash:<id> id "1234" created "2010-01-01" author "John"`

Before I was using `SORT` to fetch the top 10 posts (and paginate easily), like this:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array(0, 10),
    'get' => 'post:*->data '
));
```

Now that I have X members to my hash I'm wondering what is the best solution.

Is it:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array($offset, $limit),
    'get' => 'post:*->data '
));
```

Or maybe:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array($offset, $limit),
    'get' => '#'
));

foreach($data as $post_id) {
   $posts[] = $this->redis->hGetAll('post:'.$post_id);
}
```

Or finally:

```
$key = 'posts';
$data = $this->redis->sort($key, array(
    'by' => 'nosort',
    'limit' => array($offset, $limit),
    'get' => '#'
));

$pipeline = $this->redis->multi();
foreach ($data as $post_id) {
    $pipeline->hGetAll('post:'.$post_id);
}

return $pipeline->exec();
```

Or something else that I don't know yet? 
What is the best, faster way to do this?

Comment: Is the "X members" for each hash key are constant?  Just 'id', 'created', 'author'?

Comment: Yes but I have more than 3 fields, I have 10

Comment: Well, you can write 10 'get pattern' in the sort command, there is no limit. This is the fastest way.

Comment: Did you ever find out which method worked best?

Answer (score 0):

If you have read redis's source , you'll find that is not possible. There is a workaround that using lua script to combine 'sort' and 'hgetall' commands in a single redis invocation.

The 'get pattern' is processed by function 'lookupKeyByPattern'.
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/sort.c#L61

Answer (score -1):

If you start with the redis.io documentation on [hashes](http://redis.io/commands#hash) you'll find there are commands which allow you to get multiple hash members. In particular "[HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall)" for pulling all fields and values, or "[HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget)" for pulling a set of fields with their values.

Additionally, for setting them I would recommend setting them in one pass with "[HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset)"

Comment: I want to do it from the Set not the hash. I know `hashgetall` but this is not what I'm looking for